# pytest name is not defined

Tags: python, pytest

I'm following this tutorial to setup pytest with my project. I create a new project with the following structure and code:

```
/src
    /main.py

/tests
     /test_pytest.py
```

main.py

```
    def main():

    # Bunch of stuff

       print("End.")

# Entry point of the program
if (__name__ == '__main__'): 
    main()
```

test_pytest.py

```
import src.main as main

def test_main():
    assert main.main() == 4
```

The unittest assertion will obviously fail but it doesn't matter. Visual Studio discovers this test but says the following:

```
NameError: name 'main' is not definedpytest(./tests/test_pytest.py::test_main)
```

I don't understand why I cannot name my unit test? It doesn't seem to matter what name I use.

Comment: Did you import unittest?

Comment: Make sure you have the quotes around the string ```__main__```. Also, you may need to turn the src and tests directories into modules adding a file ```__init__.py``` in the directory. Depending on where you execute your test, you may need to add the current directory to the current path (which you can do by importing sys and immediately after a line ```sys.path.append(".")```).

Comment: Might just be a copy/paste error, but it looks like your `def main` is indented 4 spaces from the left. if python is to recognise `main()` function as a top-level part of the `main` module (i.e. if `main.main()` should work), then it should not be indented. It should appear at column 0 in the file

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
from src import main

def test_main():
    assert main.main() == 4
```